# How install ADB and Fastboot on elementary os?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, android

Is `android-tools` package available in elementary? If true how can I install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ADB` and `Fastboot` are available in the `webupd8` PPA (including backports for Ubuntu 12.04, 11.10 and 11.04 as well as for older versions of elementary OS).  You can install these tools using their PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

Note: **android-tools** packages is included in Ubuntu 12.10 and newer.  This means that, in Freya and up, you can skip the first two commands and only do the last command.

Comment: you can install them without adding an external ppa.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

This command will install ADB and Fastboot for you. elementary OS Freya is built on top of Ubuntu 14.04 so it has the very same package repositories as Ubuntu 14.04.

The current answer asks you to add a custom PPA which shouldn't be encouraged if software is available in the official repositories.

Comment: But the current answer is more complex. Because I asked it how to install in all version of Elementary os and your answer only works on Freya